# Why can't I connect to my passport middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to set up passport for authentication, but I can't figure out why I can't connect. The post request is received, but I'm not sure why the authenticate function isn't working or how to debug it.  The post request is received by the router here

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const router = express.Router();

require("../auth/auth");

router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Posted request recieved");
  passport.authenticate('register', { session: false }, async (err, user, info) => {
    console.log("Worked");
    res.send("Worked");
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```

And my passport middleware is defined here in /auth/auth:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use('register',
      new localStrategy(
        {
          usernameField: 'username',
          passwordField: 'password',      
          passReqToCallback : true 
        },
        (async (req, username, password, done) => {
          try {
              console.log("Connected!");
          }
          catch(error) {
              console.log("Error: " error)
          }
          finally { return done(null) }
        })
      )
    );
```

The error I'm receiving is that the callback function is never called. The post request is received, but it never calls the ansnnc function I defined in the passport middleware. "Connected!" is never printed. I'm not sure how to fix this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `done()` in your middleware: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

Without that, you're stuck in it and your server never replies to the request.

Comment: I added done(), although that's not the problem. The callback function itself is never being called, as "Connected" is never printed.

Answer (score 0):

try like this for authenticate if you use Mongoose

possportLocal.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const { validPassword } = require("../lib/passwordUtils");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require("./Model");

const customFields = {
    usernameField : "username",
    passwordField : "password"
}

const verifyCallback = (username, password, done)=>{
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username." });
        }
        const isValid = validPassword(password,user.hash,user.salt) //it's a function that check password
        if (!isValid) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password." });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
}

const strategy = new LocalStrategy(customFields , verifyCallback);

passport.use(strategy)


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```

in app.js

```
require('./config/passportLocal');
var passport = require('passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

route.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/login-failure",
    successRedirect: "login-success",
  })
);
```